# passing variable in routes functions (node)

Tags: node.js, express

I am attempting to pass a variable from a function in my routes files but I don't believe i'm heading in the right direction. I looked into writing to a local file initially and when I realized how bad of an idea that was i looked into storing it in a cookie or a database but I feel the solution is simpler than that.

My code is as follows

```
router.post('/input', function(req, res, err) {

 main.getStackoverflowData(req.body, function(err) {

    if (err) {
        var vm = {
            title: 'Alchemy API Dashboard | ',
            pageTitle: "Input",
            input: req.body

        };

        return res.render('/input', vm);
    }
    var vm = {

    };
    res.render('input', vm);
});

});
```

my `getStackOverFlowData()` it returns a string but I don't understand how to reference it to display it to a view using hbs locals.

I assumed when i wrote the function I would do something akin to this

```
var vm = {
    data: main.getStackoverflowData()
    }
```

Comment: It should probably be - if (!err) -  you want to render data if there's no errors, right?

Comment: no all that one does is catch an error and rerender the page the user is on with the data they had input. all this does right now is attempt to process the data.